# May I always use a stressed pronoun to replace an animate noun, even when I could have used a direct or indirect object pronoun instead?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I know that the pronoun *en* can't be used to replace individual/specific humans. The following sentences illustrate this:

> (5) J'ai peur *de rater mon examen.* --> J'*en* ai peur.
> (6) J'ai peur *de mon prof.* --> J'ai peur *de lui*.
>
> (taken from p. 234 of "The structure of modern standard French"by
> Maj-Britt Mosegaard Hansen)

We aren't allowed to replace *de mon prof* with the pronoun *en*, so the most we can replace with a pronoun is replacing *mon prof* with the stressed pronoun *lui*.

I'm wondering if I can always use "lui" in a similar way, even when I *could* replace the preposition as well. Is the following is allowed? (Original sentences taken from page 21 of the same book) :

> J'ai remercié *Paul* de son cadeau.
> --> J'ai remercié *lui* de son cadeau.
>
> J'ai parlé de l'affaire à *Max*.
> --> J'ai parlé de l'affaire à *lui*.

Comment: Your first example is not possible. You'd have to say *Je l'ai remercié de/pour son cadeau.* I'd probably prefer *pour* in this instance, but *de* is possible too. If you want to emphasize *lui*, you can say *Je l'ai remercié, lui, de son cadeau.* Your second example is possible, but only if *lui* is strongly emphasized (for example, in opposition to someone else you might have told about it, e.g., *J'en ai parlé à lui, pas à elle.*) If *lui* isn't stressed, you say *Je lui ai parlé de l'affaire*.

Comment: Check transitivity first.  J'ai parlé de l'affaire **à Max** = Je **lui** ai parlé de l'affaire.  Yes, because: parler à quelqu'un de quelque chose. Whereas: remercier quelqu'un de/pour takes a direct object, not an indirect one:  Je l'ai remercié de son cadeau.

Comment: In light of LPH's answer below, let me clarify that I didn't say that *de* was improper. I said that my own preference would be for *pour*. However, LPH's evidence shows that *de* is more common here than is *pour*.

Comment: @Anonymous I apologize for the misrepresentation of your opinion in my answer; I must have read it with too little care. I made a correction to my answer.

Comment: @LPH Aucun problème. J'ai trouvé ce Ngram intéressant.

Answer (score 1):

**I**  *J'ai remercié lui de son cadeau.*

Cela n'est correct en aucun cas.

"De" is quite proper in this context ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remerci%C3%A9+de+son+cadeau%2Cremerci%C3%A9+pour+son+cadeau&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cremerci%C3%A9%20de%20son%20cadeau%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cremerci%C3%A9%20de%20son%20cadeau%3B%2Cc0)), even if, as **user Anonymous** shows in a comment,  some might prefer "pour" ; it is, however, difficult to find "pour" wrong; [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22remerci%C3%A9%20pour%20son%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) is a full page of cases of similar contexts. Il semblerait que le nombre important de cas récents montre une influence provenant de l'anglais, bien que l'usage ne soit pas pris à l'anglais (des cas datent du 19ième siècle).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/remercier)) ♦ [Avec un compl. prép. introd. par de, de + prop. inf./ compl., pour, et précisant la cause] Remercier qqn de sa complaisance, de sa franchise; remercier qqn de l'envoi (d'un colis,...); remercier qqn pour son accueil.

The only way to formulate this is as follows.

Je l'ai remercié de son cadeau.

**II** *J'ai parlé de l'affaire à lui.*

This is also incorrect, except in cases when a  corrective is necessary in the dialogue, as follows.

- — Tu leur a parlé de l'affaire alors ? Qu'est-ce qu'ils en pensent ?
  — J'ai parlé de l'affaire à lui ; elle n'était pas là.  (*"lui" is  stressed in this case.*)

This is also correct when there is a modification such as found in the following examples.

- J'ai parlé de l'affaire *seulement* à lui.
- Je n'ai parlé de l'affaire qu'à lui.
- J'ai parlé de l'affaire à lui-même, oui, je lui ai parlé en personne.

If one wants to insist upon the fact that others were excluded, "à lui"  (stressed) is fronted. This formulation is also used to insist on who was the recipient of a particular action, but then "lui" is not stressed.

- À lui j'ai parlé de l'affaire.